# Special sized-color behind element with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, background-color

I am trying to color in an element in HTML with CSS but I want the color to be a certain size, relative to the text.

I want the color to be about 1/2 as tall as the text and slightly longer. Any way I try to do this messes up the layout and moves elements around.

**HTML**

```
<div class="no-left-padding col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
          <div class="colored">
              <h1 class="blog-title"><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/">{{ site.title }}</a></h1>
          </div>
          <h2 class="blog-desc">{{ site.description }}</h2>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.colored {
  opacity: 0.8;
  height:25px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255,218,50,0.4);
}
```

My problem is the bottom `<h2>` is being moved up under the top `<h1>`. I know that this is because the `<div>` I am encasing the `<h1>` in is having its height decreased, but I don't know how else to achieve the effect I want.

Here is a diagram to help you understand what I want:

[image]

Comment: You should include what you've tried that "_messes up the layout_" in your question.

Comment: Add some code to see what you have done and how to help you easier

Comment: Where's the `CSS//HTML` you've tried? Posting only an image isn't useful to anyone trying to help you.

Comment: @OhHendrie thanks for the input, it obviously won't look like that with a gradient but thats what I had to work with for the mockup.

Comment: @CarrieKendall just placed in HTML and CSS

Comment: @OhHendrie I'm sorry are you having a bad day? Clearly I don't know how to solve this problem so I did the best I could giving as much context as I can. If I knew what code would work don't you think I wouldn't need to post on Stack Overflow? Sorry I wasted your precious time when there are plenty of other questions you could be equally as unhelpful for. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this will give you the effect your looking for, you can add the background colour to a `<span>` and position that absolute inside the heading.

html:

```
<div>
    <h1 class="blog-title"><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/">{{ site.title }}</a>
    <span class="colored"></span></h1>    
</div>
```

css:

```
.blog-title{
    position: relative;
}
.colored {
  opacity: 0.8;
  height:25px;
  width: 300px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255,218,50,0.4);
}
```

---

**Second question**

Need to make some changes to get this to work. Move the span from outside to inside the `<a href></a>`then apply the `position:relative` to the  by adding a class. See the updated code below.

html:

```
<div>
    <h1 class="blog-title"><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/" class="color-container">greagaregare<span class="colored"></span></a>
    </h1>    
</div>

<div>
    <h1 class="blog-title"><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/" class="color-container">aergae<span class="colored"></span></a></h1>    
</div>
```

css:

```
.color-container{
    position: relative;
}
.colored {
  opacity: 0.8;
  height:22%;
  width: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255,218,50,1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That is more along the lines of what I would want, but is there a way I can make the sizing dynamic by using percents for the height and width? I know that the position: absolute will make percents just have it fill up that percentage of the entire page, instead of the space the word takes up.

Comment: You could look at using em or rem instead of pixels for the width and height, also make sure you give the h1 class blog-title a position of relative updated the code to include this.

Comment: Also percentage values will work, the width will be taken from the width of h1

Comment: So I've got another question if you could help. I have `<h1>`'s throughout the page, some are in certain sized `<div>`'s while others span their entire page length. Is there are way I could treat each `<h1>`'s width to only be as long as the text it contains? This would allow my `<span class="colored">` to be more dynamic, as of now I need to make new ones for each case.

Comment: Seriously thank you so much, I have the exact effect I wanted now.